# Pusher Swift member added/removed event

Tags: swift, swift2, real-time, pusher, pusherswift

I'm using [Pusher Swift](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-swift) right now, but I can't find a properly way to handle the member_added and member_removed methods. In [LibPusher](https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher) (objective-c implementation) exists **PTPusherPresenceChannelDelegate** with memberAdded and memberRemoved methods, but in Pusher Swift doesn't.

Subscribing it's working fine

```
let presenceChannel = pusher.subscribe("presence-channel")
    presenceChannel.bind("pusher:subscription_succeeded", callback: { (data: AnyObject?) -> Void in
        //It's ok!
    })
```

How to handle this events ? thanks

Comment: Any ideas about what happens wth that? I'm also trying to get this messages but, even I see it in the pusher debug console, I do not receive it in my code. Have you found a solution? Do you get back to Objetive-C library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you subscribe to a presence channel you can include closures to handle "onMemberAdded" and "onMemberRemoved" events.

From the PusherSwift [cocoapod docs](https://cocoapods.org/pods/PusherSwift):

```
let onMemberAdded = { (member: PresenceChannelMember) in
    //Do something with the new member
    print(member)
}
let onMemberRemoved = { (member: PresenceChannelMember) in
    //Do something with the removed member
    print(member)
}
let chan = pusher.subscribe("presence-channel", onMemberAdded: onMemberAdded, onMemberRemoved: onMemberRemoved)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this methods weren't present before, nice update.